# Mismatch in assigning IP address to a buffer and printing contents of buffer

Tags: c, ip-address, memcpy, raw-sockets

I am implementing raw sockets in C. In the code below, I am parsing the IP header I received from sender.

```
a.  I will send back the ack as well so storing IP address received in a buffer(ret_ip). 
b.  I don't have another computer so using lo (local loop back) as my interface.

//first two printf statements are printing the right address, 10.100.207.74
//daddr SENT = 32.112.247.9saddr SENT = 36.112.247.9
```

How can I get it correct?
I think this problem is due to memcpy whose first argument is pointing to unsigned char while second argument is pointing to _be32.

What I actually want to do in my program is : ret_ip's first 4 bytes should contain the destination address and next 4 the source address. Then I will create IP header and make dest addr=source addr and source-addr=dest-addr. and send ACK to sender.

```
char* ParseIPHeader(unsigned char *packet,int len)
{
struct ethhdr *ethernet_header;
struct iphdr *ip_header;
char *ret_ip;   
ethernet_header=(struct ethhdr *)packet;

if(ntohs(ethernet_header->h_proto)==ETH_P_IP)
{
    if(len>=(sizeof(struct ethhdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)))
    {
        ip_header=(struct iphdr*)(packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        ret_ip=malloc(2*(sizeof(ip_header->daddr)));
        printf("Dest IP address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(ip_header->daddr));  
        printf("Source IP address: %s\n",inet_ntoa(ip_header->saddr));
        memcpy(ret_ip,&(ip_header->daddr),sizeof(ip_header->daddr));
        memcpy(ret_ip+4,&(ip_header->saddr),4);
        printf("daddr SENT = %s",inet_ntoa(ret_ip));  
        printf("saddr SENT = %s",inet_ntoa(ret_ip+4));
    }
    else
    printf("IP packet does not have full header\n");
}
else
{ 
//not an IP packet
}
return ret_ip;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

first problem is your memory allocation

```
ret_ip=malloc(2*(ip_header->daddr));
```

it should be

```
ret_ip=malloc(2*(sizeof(ip_header->daddr)));
```

but why you are not using the ip_hdr struct again ? for example

```
struct iphdr *ret_ip = malloc(sizeof(iphdr));
ret_ip->daddr = ip_header->saddr;
ret_ip->saddr = ip_header->daddr;
```

i suggest this solution is much easier ;)

Comment: ok one last thing.. I need to call *CreateIpHeader(source_addr,dest_addr)* what would be the type of arguments for this function?

Comment: sorry, i dont't now this funtion. if you plan to self implement this funtion you should use in_addr_t ( u_int32). inside the funtion you have to convert your address in network byte order by calling inet_addr()